# How does OpenCV projectPoints perform transformations before projecting?

Tags: python, opencv

I have two 3d points that I am trying to project onto a 2d image plane using `cv::projectPoints()`. Originally the points are not in the cameras frame of reference so I have to transform them. I am testing the validity of the method's transformations.

First I manually apply a translation to my points as well as a -90 degree rotation about the x axis via rotation matrix `matr`.

```
import numpy as np
import math
import cv2

# center of projection
cop = np.array([-14.45194, 34.59882, 19.11343])

# get rotation
r_vec = cv2.Rodrigues(np.array(matr))[0]
print([round(math.degrees(i),2) for i in r_vec])

# init arrays
coords = np.array([[4.27874, 115.15968, 18.1621], [27.52924, 113.3441, 17.70207]])
transformed_coords = np.zeros(coords.shape)

# transform coords
for b, _ in enumerate(coords):

    arr = np.array([0,0,0])

    # translate
    for r in range(3):
        arr[r] = coords[b][r] - cop[r]

    # rotate
    transformed_coords[b] = np.dot(matr, arr)
```

Next I pass in the transformed coords into `projectPoints()` and compare the resulting 2d points with the points I get by passing the transformation into the method.

```
points_2d = cv2.projectPoints(np.array(transformed_coords), np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0]), np.array([0.0,0.0,0.0]), cam_matrix, distortion)[0]
print("Manual Transformation Projection: ")
print(points_2d )

points_2d = cv2.projectPoints(np.array(coords), np.array(r_vec), np.array(cop), cam_matrix, distortion)[0]
print("\nOpenCV Transformation Projection: ")
print(points_2d )
```

Output:

```
[-90.0, 0.0, 0.0] # matr rotation 

Manual Transformation Projection: 
[[[596.41419111 538.38054858]]

 [[159.74685131 557.65317027]]]

OpenCV Transformation Projection: 
[[[1101.1539809  -274.07081182]]

 [[ 738.45477039 -281.42273082]]]
```

Why are they different?

By the way heres the cam matrix and distortion if you want to recreate it:

```
cam_matrix = np.array([[1561.9015217711233, 0, 944.3790845611046], [0, 1557.8348925840205, 538.3374859400157], [0, 0, 1]])
distortion = np.array([-0.2136432557736835, 0.20055112514542725, 0.00054631323043295, -0.00067835485282051, -0.07781645541334031])
```

Comment: Rvec and tvec provided to the projectPoints function is be the camera pose. If I understand correctly in your first example it is the object pose instead?

Comment: projectPoints expects those to be, *not* the camera pose, but the *object's* pose in the camera's coordinate system/frame (transforming points from object frame to camera frame) -- if you already transformed your points and they're camera-local, you should pass empty/all-zero rvec and tvec then, because there's no more transformation to be done.

Comment: the rvec is **NOT** euler angles. it is an axis-angle encoding. length of vector = amount of rotation. vector = axis of rotation.

Comment: what are you even doing there with "center of projection" and all that? I don't see how you construct `matr` either. and why do you _subtract_ `cop` (which appears to be your `tvec`)? it's supposed to be added.

Comment: please review [mre].

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz cop is the exact 3d location of the camera, so yes I thought it was my tvec. Lets say you are trying to make cop at the origin. Would you not subtract each component of every other point in the environment by its respective cop component? (including cop)

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz so rvec is a quaternion?

Comment: I said axis-angle representation. I explained what it is. I did not say "quaternions". -- the location of the camera (relative to a world frame) is immaterial. you need all scene geometry referenced to the camera itself. a "world" frame is irrelevant to this whole operation.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz the reality of my situation is that I start with everything in the world frame. In this case is it appropriate to pass the camera's world frame location as tvec?

Comment: it is not. you need to calculate the object pose relative to the camera: `T_cam_obj = T_cam_world @ T_world_obj = inv(T_world_cam) @ T_world_obj` (`@` is matrix multiplication, numpy feature, inv is np.linalg.inv, those are 4x4 matrices)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

to clarify a few things:

- `projectPoints` expects rvec and tvec to be the *object's* pose in the camera's coordinate system/frame (transforming points from object frame to camera frame)
- If you already transformed your points and they're camera-local, you should pass empty/all-zero rvec and tvec
- The rvec is **NOT** Euler angles. It is an axis-angle encoding. Its length equals the amount of rotation (in radians, not degrees). The vector itself is the axis of rotation.

Issues you should investigate:

- Assuming your `cop` array is supposed to be the `tvec`, you are supposed to add that, not subtract it.
- Present `matr`. It is not contained in your code.
- use `numpy` effectively. Don't iterate and assign individual elements of arrays.

If you have a world frame, and both your camera and object are defined in the world frame, then you have `T_world_cam` and `T_world_obj`.

For `projectPoints()`, you need `T_cam_obj`, or ***<sup>cam</sup>T<sub>obj</sub>*** (math notation).

This transformation...

- transforms geometry from the object frame (input, right side) into the camera frame (output, left side)
- expresses the object's pose relative to the camera frame

The equations:

```py
T_cam_obj = T_cam_world @ T_world_obj
T_cam_obj = inv(T_world_cam) @ T_world_obj # np.linalg.inv
```

Write utility functions that convert between rvec,tvec (for OpenCV) and 4x4 matrix representation (for calculating without going insane):

```py
def rtvec_to_matrix(rvec=(0,0,0), tvec=(0,0,0)):
    "Convert rotation vector and translation vector to 4x4 matrix"
    rvec = np.asarray(rvec)
    tvec = np.asarray(tvec)

    T = np.eye(4)
    (R, jac) = cv.Rodrigues(rvec)
    T[:3, :3] = R
    T[:3, 3] = tvec.squeeze()
    return T

def matrix_to_rtvec(matrix):
    "Convert 4x4 matrix to rotation vector and translation vector"
    (rvec, jac) = cv.Rodrigues(matrix[:3, :3])
    tvec = matrix[:3, 3]
    return rvec, tvec
```

Comment: This definitely helps, but I still have issues. I didn't implement your methods exactly but I think I got the idea: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73355354/why-are-these-opencv-projected-points-incorrect

Comment: Hmm, my Tl;Dr from all of this is that the docs of Calib3d are really confusing... I have two questions: 1) Given that `T_world_cam` is a column vector, inverting it leads to a column vector. Performing matrix multiplication with `T_world_obj`, which in my understanding would also be a column vector, would then lead to `T_cam_obj` being a scalar. Therefore, my understanding must be wrong, but where?

Comment: Ah, nvm, I just discovered that `T_world_cam` and `T_world_obj` are projection matrices, not translation vectors

Comment: So, do I understand this correctly: If my object coordinate system is equal to the world coordinate system, `T_world_obj` would be an identity matrix and `T_cam_obj` would thus simplify to `T_cam_obj = T_cam_world = inv(T_world_cam)`?

Comment: *"T_world_cam is a column vector"* it is ***not***. -- the transform from one frame to itself is the identity transform, hence the identity matrix. -- if you have questions, please open a new question.