# Camera extrinsic matrix from camera location and rotation

Tags: c++, opencv, computer-vision, camera, homography

I am trying to convert a 2D pixel point into a 3D world position on a plane where Z = 0. Similar to [this](https://answers.opencv.org/question/62779/image-coordinate-to-world-coordinate-opencv/) question on the opencv forum. Check it out for a very nice illustration of the setup.

**Some explination.** To convert between image coordinates and world coordinates a homography matrix is commonly used. The Homography matrix consist of an internal matrix and an external matrix.

```
    Pix    Internal       External     Position
    [u]   [ f 0 Px 0] [ R11 R12 R13 Tx] [x]
    [v] = [ 0 f Py 0] [ R21 R22 R23 Ty] [y]
    [1]   [ 0 0 0  0] [ R31 R32 R33 Tz] [z]
                      [ 0   0   0   1 ] [1]
```

```
[Homograpy] = [Interal][External]
```

Using the homography matrix it is possible to convert from world position to camera position. Then inversing the homograhy matrix it is possible to convert pixel position to world position. As long as Z is set as depth is lost when converting to pixels, so we insert a new value.

How to combine internal and external matrices into a homography matrix and use the homography matrix can be found several places. Some C++ Github code for this can be found [here](https://github.com/rodolfoap/OpenCV-2Dto3D).

Not the internal matrix has to be using OpenCv camera calibration which is its own topic. Now I have already done this so I will be skipping this topic.

The external matrix consists of a rotation matrix [R] and a translation vector |t|. In other OpenCv questions the rotation matrix and translation vector is calculated as follows:

```
solvePnP(world_points, image_points, cameraMatrix, distCoeffs, rotationVector, translationVector);
Rodrigues(rotationVector, rotationMatrix);
```

**Now I my use case** the camera position and rotation are not fixed. So it would be a lot of work to create mapped world and image positions for each pose. However, I would know the camera location and rotation in world space. So is it possible to use these to construct the extrinsic matrix?

So of the reading that I have done have hinted at that it should be possible: The formulas [here](https://miaodx.github.io/blogs/unrealcv_digest/camera_pose/), suggests that is possible to calculate extrinsic matrix as follows:

```
[External] = [R|t] = [R| -RC]
```

In this equation C is the position of the camera expressed in world coordinates. So with C known I only need R to find the translation vector.

Now this article here [here](https://miaodx.github.io/blogs/unrealcv_digest/camera_pose/) inserts the [Roll, Pitch, Yaw] (θ, φ, ψ) in radians into x,y,z-axis rotation matrices to create the final combined rotation matrix.

[image: Rotation Matrix calculation]

Now I have tried tried doing this before but never figured out the order of rotation. Since that matters a lot when it comes to rotation matrices.

For example would the order be the same as above if the camera is rotated -90* around the Z-axis and then 90* around the X-axis, to get to the position as shown in the image bellow? Or does the order not matter in this case, as we are not rotating the object but describing its rotation?

One other option could be to instead create the rotation vector then pass it thought the Rodrigues to then get the rotation matrix. As the other OpenCv examples do. I would then just need to find a way to express the rotation vector.

[image]

Comment: I'd suggest working with 4x4 matrices. composition, then, works with inversions and matrix multiplications. a lot cleaner than gluing parts together. also, notation: emulate math notation, where a postsubscript denotes the "input" frame and a presuperscript denotes resulting frame. for vectors/points, it should be a presuperscript. -- `Rodrigues` is right. turn the axis-angle representation into 3x3 matrix, then use that (compose into 4x4 matrix or whatever)

Comment: OpenCV's coordinate system, for cameras/pictures, is right-handed, X right, Y down, Z far. for "worlds", you decide, but also right-handed. -- to reiterate: `rvec` is not euler angles, and it's not a quaternion. it's an **axis-angle encoding**. its magnitude encodes the amount of rotation in radians. the vector represents the axis of rotation. -- your question would benefit from more pictures, and more numbers/vectors/matrices (with numbers in them). if you can express a fact in anything *other than prose*, you should.

Comment: browse the [`calib3d` tag in the new opencv forum](https://forum.opencv.org/tag/calib3d). people have written plenty of stuff on the topic.

Comment: some more related stuff: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/73340550/how-does-opencv-projectpoints-perform-transformations-before-projecting

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz Thanks for the feedback, will definitely take a look around and see what I can find.

Comment: Edited the question and tried to include more pictures and code. Have not gotten around to checking all of you links yet @ChristophRackwitz, but form a quick glance it looks like i might find a solution there. If I do hope to be able to answer my own question.

Comment: I still can't tell what _the question_ is, or why it exists. you seem to understand the math well enough to apply it and come to a solution that is self-consistent. I'm grepping for `?` and find two instances. I'll address those in a moment.

Comment: rotations aren't special. order **always** matters (matrix multiplication). as for the rotations you propose... my brain refuses to follow because that's not leading anywhere productive. if you want the camera to be oriented like in the picture, that is either 180 degrees around X, or 180 degrees around Y, or either *plus* whatever rotation around Z you desire. instead of facing +Z, it's facing -Z. -- I have no idea how to interpret your question to induce a sensible answer. it's just too broad/unfocused. this site works because questions are "reusable" and answers aren't chapters from a book